# Displaying relation graphs between objects

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'd like to know if it's possible using a .NET library to create something like this in .NET :

[image]

The goal is not to generate the image, but to display it in the form and being able to click on the cells and the edges to do things.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out [Microsoft Automatic Graph Layout](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/msagl/).

Comment: Thank you much it's exactly what i was looking for.